# How to trace all system calls for executable file in Linux

Tags: linux, system-calls, strace, audit-logging

I have exe file in ubuntu. I'm using the wine tool to run it. However, my question is there any way to trace and log all system calls that are involved when the exe is running?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`strace`](https://strace.io/).

Comment: Do you mean all the calls that the executable makes to the wine runtime or the calls that wine makes to the system?

Comment: @HenriqueBucher basically the executable file acts as an interface to receive data from a sensor and display those data. system calls that this interface will produce such as Filesystem and Network I/O, process creation and memory access